# MySQL Optimize avg, sum query have left join nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

Is anyway to optimize this query for MySQL 5.1?

I have "Calls" table, have fields "Caller" (from number), "Callee" (to number) and "Duration", this query work fine in SQLite, but it is very slow in MySQL with huge data 14billion record.

I have index on Caller field.

```
select A.Caller, ifnull(aCallOut, 0) as CallOut, round((ifnull(aDuration, 0) / 60), 2) as Duration, round((ifnull(aAverage, 0) / 60), 2) as Average, Times, 0, 0, 0, 0
from
  (
    select Caller, sum(duration) as aDuration, count(*) Times -- sum of duration of each caller
    from Calls
    group by Caller
  ) As A

left join
  (
    select Caller, avg(duration) as aAverage -- i want avg duration of numbers that calling more than 0 seconds
    from Calls
    where Duration > 0
    group by Caller
  ) as C
  on A.Caller = C.Caller

left join
  (
    select Caller, count(*) as aCallOut -- i need to count how many numbers that caller called, ignoring the duplicating calls
    from
      (
        select Caller, count(*) aCount
        from Calls
        group by Caller, Callee
      ) as D
    group by Caller
  ) as B
  on A.Caller = B.Caller
```

Comment: The first two can be merged fairly simply, but I am having a hard time understanding the point of the third part; `Callee` is referenced nowhere else, not used in the join, and there is nothing merge (sum, average, etc...) multiple callee values on the Caller they joined to.

Comment: Nevermind, Gordon's answer below makes that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with conditional aggregation:

```
select Caller, sum(duration) as aDuration, count(*) as Times,
       avg(case when duration > 0 then duration end) as aAverage,
       count(distinct Callee) as aCallOut
from Calls
group by Caller;
```

Small note:  if `Callee` is ever `NULL`, then `aCallOut` might be off by 1.

Comment: "If no when_value or search_condition matches the value tested and the CASE statement contains no ELSE clause, a Case not found for CASE statement error results."https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . You are confusing the`case` statement with the ANSI standard `case` expression.  The `case` expression does not require an `ELSE ` clause (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

Comment: Ah, my mistake... and some quick testing confirms AVG disregards NULLs. Also confirmed SUM does as well, I could've sworn SUM used to return NULL if any value processed was NULL...

Comment: @Uueerdo . . . Aggregation functions only return `NULL` if *all* arguments are `NULL` -- except for `COUNT()`, which returns 0.

Comment: Maybe that mistaken impression was from when I had to work in MSAccess against a linked MySQL database; just goes to show that there is always something to (un)learn. :)

Comment: Thank you, that help me, what is new for me AVG and Count did not take Null values, and Count "distinct".

Answer (score 0):

To merge the first two...

```
SELECT Caller
, sum(duration) as aDuration -- sum of duration of each caller
, count(*) Times
, SUM(IF(duration>0, duration, 0)) / NULLIF(SUM(IF(duration>0, 1, 0)),0)  -- avg(duration) as aAverage
FROM Calls
GROUP BY Caller
```

Edit: This may have a divide by zero error if a Caller has no `duration > 0` rows.

Edit#2: Wrapping the denominator in `NULLIF(,0)` prevents that error.